# Typescript and squelize :- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js

The error occurs when connecting to `mysql` in typescript.

The error:

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
   errno: 1064,
   sqlState: '42000',
   sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UUIDV4 NOT NULL auto_increment , `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `completed
` TINY' at line 1",
    sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `typescript_table` (`id` UUIDV4 NOT NULL auto_increment , `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `completed` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME N
OT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;',
    parameters: undefined
  },
  sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `typescript_table` (`id` UUIDV4 NOT NULL auto_increment , `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `completed` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT
 NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;',
  parameters: {}
```

**folder structure**

```
  - src
    |--modal
    |    |-index.ts
    |--config
    |   |-database.config.ts
    app.ts
```

### app.ts

```
import express,{Request,Response} from "express";
// import  {ErrorRequestHandler} from "express";
import HttpError from "http-errors";
import exampleRoute from "./routes/routes";
import db from './config/database.config';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import  {CrudInstance} from './modal/index';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());
// app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))

db.sync().then(() => {
    console.log('connect to db');
})

// app.get("/api",exampleRoute);

app.post("/create",async(req:Request,res:Response) => {
    // console.log("data from postman --->",req.body);
    const id =uuidv4();
    try {
        const record = await CrudInstance.create({...req.body,id})
        return res.json({record,msg:"successfully create table"});
    } catch(e) {
        return res.json({ msg:"fail to create", status:500, route:'/create' });
    }
})

app.use(() => {
    throw HttpError(404,"Not Found");
});

app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log(`server up on port no http://localhost:${port}`);
})
// const errorHandler:ErrorRequestHandler = (err,req,res,next) => {
    //   console.log(err.message , err.statusCode);
    //   if (res.headersSent) {
    //       return next(err);
    //   }
    //
    //   res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json({message:err.message || "An Unknow Error"});
// }
```

### modal/index.ts

```
import {Sequelize,Model, DataTypes} from "sequelize";
import db from '../config/database.config';

interface crudAttributes {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    completed: boolean
}

export class CrudInstance extends Model<crudAttributes> {}


CrudInstance.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        title:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        completed: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: false,
        },
    }, {
        sequelize:db,
        tableName:'typescript_table'
    }
);


// CrudInstance.sync();
```

### config/database.config.ts

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';


const db = new Sequelize("CRUD","xyz","xyz",{
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: "mysql",
    logging: false
});

// db.sync();

export default db;
```

Comment: mysql has no datatype uuidv4 also you can't incremnet

Comment: so what i can do now  and i also remove uuidv4 but does not work

Comment: use string and remove the auto_incremet

Comment: thanks @nbk working but in table id length is so big

Comment: Thanks @nbk, didn't notice my data types was different this whole time.

Answer (score 0):

here is updated model
you can change Datatypes.UUIDV4 to UUID

updated code is

```js
CrudInstance.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        title:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        completed: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: false,
        },
    }, {
        sequelize:db,
        tableName:'typescript_table'
    }
);
```